# Is Symbolic Execution a formal Verification technique?

Tags: formal-verification, symbolic-execution

I have spent two days researching on Formal Methods and formal Verification to be more specific. I also came across Symbolic Execution and I don't know whether this is a formal verification technique? why and why not?
I am curious about development of formally verified software.

Answer (score 1):

Symbolic execution is a method that can be used in Formal Verification.

Here's a relatively introductory article that should help: https://patrickalphac.medium.com/formal-verification-symbolic-execution-the-security-silver-bullet-38e0ac9072eb

For stack-overflow to be useful, you'll have to be more specific.